# How exactly can the eye detect electromagentic waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, vision

From my understanding, EM waves are traveling disturbances in the electric and magnetic fields. They travel at the speed of light, since Maxwell's equation imply
$$\nabla^2 \mathbf{B} = \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2\mathbf{B}}{\partial t} \quad \text{and} \quad \nabla^2 \mathbf{E} = \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2\mathbf{E}}{\partial t}$$

Which are the standard wave equation for waves traveling at speed $c$. Historically, this led to the realization that light is actually an EM wave.

The thing is, that the only physical meaning of EM fields is given by the fact that they describe forces acting on charged particles (specifically, $\mathbf{F} =q(\mathbf{v}\times \mathbf{B} +\mathbf{E})$ . I believe this would mean that the only way to observe an EM field (or, in this case, EM waves) is to have it act upon a charged particle. Does this mean that our eyes, essentially, somehow, detect charged particles? If so how?
(I think we actually detect the strength of the wave, but the point is the same)

Or am I missing something fundamental...

Comment: Well human photoreceptors cells certainly are made of atoms and molecules which are constituted of protons, electrons, and neutrons (which have weak magnetic moments).

Comment: That atoms and molecules follow quantum mechanics?for example  see https://www.aao.org/education/editors-choice/quantum-biology-of-retina

Comment: Thank you both!